# Динамический массив

Tags: c++

```
int size = busNodes.size();
double * distancearray=new double[size];
for(int value = 0;value<busNodes.size();value++)
{
    distancearray[value]=Infinity;
}
```

Во время первого запуска программы, количество автобусных остановок – 234, но я хочу затем поменять и посмотреть, как программа все посчитает.

Проблема заключается лишь в одном, при создании массива, он не создает 234 остановки с дистанцией бесконечность, а создает лишь одну.

Что я делаю не так? И было уже много тем по этой теме, только делая все, как описано в тех темах и не только тут, у меня выходит все равно одна остановка.

Comment: Цикл по `value`, а используется какая-то неизвестная `i`.

Comment: @alexolut да , спасибо за комментарий , но в программе все стоит правильно , тут ошибся.. Суть не в этой ошибке , суть в другом

Comment: в том, что _busNodes.size()_ возвращает 1?

Comment: @Grundy Проблема в том , что у меня например 234 станции. Значит distancerray должен иметь , distancerray[0]=Infinity , distancerray[1]=Infinity итд. После прохода цикла , он возвращает distance[0]=Infinity.А где оставшиеся 233?

Comment: Что вообще такое `busNodes`? Если это какой-то `std::` контейнер, то зачем тут использовать вручную создаваемый массив через `new []`?

Comment: А вообще, Вам ещё не советовали раньше в вопросах приводить [mcve]? Если нет, то я вот очень бы рекомендовал подготовить такой код.

Comment: _После прохода цикла , он возвращает distance[0]=Infinity.А где оставшиеся 233?_ - а как ты проверяешь и где смотришь значения?

Comment: @alexolut А что тут непонятного... busnodes.size() - контейнер , который может сейчас содержать 234 , завтра 100000 станций и вручную я не хочу менять размер массива.. Поэтому решил создать динамический массив , который сам будет уже меняться

Comment: @Grundy Как минимум , я ставлю брейк поинты и смотрю , что он делает с массивом.

Comment: Почему тогда в качестве `distancearray` тоже не использовать контейнер? А отладчиком Вы проверяли, сколько итераций по циклу происходит и чему равно `size`?

Comment: @alexolut код уже готов , мне попросили только поменять массивы , на динамические , иначе , если пользователь в программе захочет сделать 150 станций , то ему надо писать везде 150 , 150 , 150 .. size = busnodes.size() , который находится в другой функции и все там работает правильно .. Уже все проверено , только дин.массив надо

Comment: @alexolut спасибо , идея хорошая с контейнером, я как-то вот начал думать о дин.массиве и забыл про контейнер.

Comment: _@Grundy Как минимум , я ставлю брейк поинты и смотрю , что он делает с массивом._ ну так тут важно **что** ты видишь и **как** ты смотришь, в некоторых отладчиках например при просмотре указателя - показывается только первый элемент

Comment: вот что я думаю. в первый раз `busNodes.size() == 10`, потом этот показатель сбрасывается и становится 1 (не знаю как, но похоже на это) 
вопрос: почему не использовать в цикле уже готовую переменную `size ` ? 

выведите в output чему равны `size`  и `busNodes.size() `

Comment: Если вы вправду хотите настоящий **динамический** массив, то используйте готовую библиотеку, или хотя бы, создайте класс, обьявите оператор []  типо так `class MyArray { int size; int * buf; public: int & operator [] (int _index) {   if (_index >= size){/*realloc*/};  return buf[_index];  }  }`, а ваш массив - вы можете путать что он динамический как в js (авторазширяемый). Он динамический как в с++ (не авторазширяемый).

Answer (score 2):

Вы не пробовали после этого сразу сделать контрольно-отладочный вывод?

```
cout << "busNodes.size() = " << busNodes.size() << endl;
for(int value = 0; value < busNodes.size(); value++)
{
    cout << "distancearray[" << value << "] = " << distancearray[value] << endl;
}
```

?
Скорее всего, у вас будет либо неверное значение `busNodes.size()`, либо вы выясните, что что-то происходит *вне* этого кода, либо - что вы неверно трактуете происходящее...

Экзотика типа

```
#define Infinity   0; break
```

не рассматривается :)